# Looping through Multiple Indices in Python

Tags: python, loops, indices

This is a cross-post from reddit (Pointed in this direction by my SO) Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

I'm mid homework project and I had a few questions about reading multiple indices. The outcome I'm looking for is to build lists that feed into each other. In this case it's to build a fruit list, then ask for how expensive the fruit are, then ask how many a customer has before displaying a total for each customer, looping around for each customer until you hit done. This is a intro to programming class writing in Python 2.7

The correct output would look like this:

```
Enter a fruit name (or done): Mango
Enter a fruit name (or done): Strawberry
Enter a fruit name (or done): Kiwi
Enter a fruit name (or done): done

Enter the price for Mango: 2.54
Enter the price for Strawberry: 0.23
Enter the price for Kiwi: .75

Enter customer name (or done): Bob
Mango($2.54) Quantity: 3
Strawberry($0.23) Quantity: 10
Kiwi($0.75) Quantity: 2

Bob's total purchase is $11.42

Enter customer name (or done): Lisa
Mango($2.54) Quantity: 10
Strawberry($0.23) Quantity: 40
Kiwi($0.75) Quantity: 20
```

Thus far, I've built a program that can (more or less) build a fruit list, ask for the price, and calculate a total but I can't quite figure out how to integrate a final 'customer list'
My code is as follows:

```
flist = []
print "Enter a fruit name (or done): " ,
fruit_name = raw_input()
while fruit_name != 'done':
  flist.append(fruit_name)
  print "Enter a fruit name (or done): ",
  fruit_name = raw_input()

print " "   

price_list = [] 
for p in flist:
  print "Enter the price for " + p + ":",
  price = float(raw_input())
  price_list.append(price)

qlist = []
for q in range(len(flist)):
  print "How many " + str(flist[q]) + ' (' + '$' +     str(price_list[q]) + ')' ":",   
  quantity = raw_input()
  qlist.append(quantity)

total = 0
for i in range(len(flist)):
  total += float(price_list[q]) * int(qlist[q])
print "Your total purchase is $ " + str(total)
```

I'm not sure how to continue from here. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, heres some ideas to get you started without doing the assignment for you:

- Given your end goal is to print out a customer list, containing what fruits they have and the customers total, you should probably store all of this data together rather than in separate lists. So think about using something like a dictionary, where your keys are the customers names, and the value is a sub dictionary containing the number of each fruit, and other relevant information. If you store all of this data together, it becomes much easier to print out a single customers info
- Probably the first thing you want to do is ask for the customer name. Then you can user this to set the first key in the dictionary.
- When you loop through the fruit names, you can then use these as additional keys for that one customer, where the value is the number of each fruit
- You'll want another dict to hold the prices for each fruit

Once you have that type of structure you can do something like this to print everything out:

```
#Get these values with loops like you're currently doing
customerDict = {"bob": {"orange": 3,"apple": 1},
                "alice": {"orange": 2,"apple": 1}}

priceDict = {"orange": 1.2, "apple": 1.1}

#get this from user input
customerName = "bob" 

total = 0

print customerName
for k,v in customerDict[customerName].items():
    print "%s (%s), Quantity: %s" % (k, str(priceDict[k]), str(v))
    total += (priceDict[k] * v)

print "Total: " + str(total)
```

Which will return something like:

```
bob
orange (1.2), Quantity: 3
apple (1.1), Quantity: 1
Total: 4.7
```